# MSXML2.DOMDocument Equivalent in Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have following macro embedded in Excel which works perfectly in Windows but it is not responding in Mac. I assume the problem is `MSXML2.DOMDocument` I use the main excel file both in Mac and Windows PC. Is there a solution to operate file both Mac and PC?

```
Sub PEAKUP_TCMB_TUM_KURLAR()
    Dim xml As Object, adres As String, tablom As Object, sat As Byte
    Range("A2:G100") = ""
    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    xml.async = False
    xml.validateOnParse = False
    adres = "https://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml"
    xml.Load adres
    Set tablom = xml.SelectNodes("//Currency")
    If tablom.Length = 0 Then GoTo cik:
    sat = tablom.Length - 1
    For i = 0 To sat
    Cells(i + 2, 1) = tablom(i).ChildNodes(1).Text
    Cells(i + 2, 2) = tablom(i).ChildNodes(3).Text
    Cells(i + 2, 3) = tablom(i).ChildNodes(4).Text
    Cells(i + 2, 4) = tablom(i).ChildNodes(5).Text
    Cells(i + 2, 5) = tablom(i).ChildNodes(6).Text
    Next i
    cik:
    Set tablom = Nothing: Set xml = Nothing: adres = vbNullString: sat = Empty
End Sub
```

Comment: Cannot verify on Mac, but you might try to use the recommended current version 6.0 (instead of the defaulting 3.0 version): `CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")` ? 
- Btw note the difference to early bound dom document syntax without point delimiters: `Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60` and      ' bzw. MSXML2.DOMDocument (=old version 3.0)
`Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60`.

Comment: You may be able to use `QueryTable` functionality on the MAC for your requirements.  And, in later versions, `Power Query` may be available.  Since `DLL`'s are a Windows feature, you won;t be able to use any version of Microsoft XML on the MAC.